# relation "weather_city" does not exist

Tags: django, heroku

When I push my django project to heroku I get "relation "weather_city" does not exist". weather is the name of the app and city is a model.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'cities'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have forgotten to make migrations.

Answer (score 0):

`heroku run bash`

`$ python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.